# Can recursion be achieved with the help of Heap data structure?

Tags: recursion, data-structures

How can I implement recursion with the help of a heap... is it a good idea? As much as I know, that heap is a wonderful data structure and can do many things which cannot be achieved by other data structures and that too very efficiently. So why dont we use Heap for implementing recursion?

Comment: actually, it's so nice that there's even a stackless version of python - http://www.stackless.com/

Comment: In most languages where you have limited stack space people are using a utility stack + iteration to do recursion.

Comment: What I am looking for is, to implement recursion using only heap i.e. no stack..? can it be achieved?